# Exception Unhandled - Dont know how to fix

Tags: c#

im getting exception unhandled at the "throw new Exception("Creditd amount must be greater than 0");"
Please help me I dont know what to do.

namespace _11_8
{
    class Account
    {
        private decimal _balance;

```
    public Account(decimal balance)
    {

    }

    public decimal Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                _balance = value;
            else
                throw new Exception("Balance cant be negative");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Credit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0)
            Balance += amount;
        else
            throw new Exception("Creditd amount must be greater than 0");
    }

    public virtual bool Debit(decimal amount)
    {
        bool OK = true;
        if (Balance - amount >= 0)
        {
            Balance -= amount;
            OK = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Debit amount exceeded account balance");
            OK = false;
        }

        return OK;
    }
}
namespace _11_8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            decimal totalCredit = 0.0M;
            SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount(1000.25M, 0.1M);

            Console.WriteLine("Start balance is {0:C}", sa.Balance);
            totalCredit = sa.CalculateInterest();
            Console.WriteLine("Total interest: {0:C}", totalCredit);
            sa.Credit(totalCredit); //adding credit to balance
            Console.WriteLine("End balance is: {0:C}", sa.Balance);
            Console.WriteLine();


            CheckingAccount ca = new CheckingAccount(1000.25M, 5.50M);
            Console.WriteLine("Start balance is {0:C}", ca.Balance);
            ca.Credit(55.25M);
            ca.Debit(925.55M);
            Console.WriteLine("Ending balance is {0:C}", ca.Balance);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code it self is throwing this exception, if method Credit(0) is provided with zero. to avoid, do not throw exceptions in methods,if it is not necessary by any mean. Use method in style of  `public virtual bool Debit(decimal amount)` and write to console instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sa.Credit(totalCredit)`, it throws an exception, due to the way you wrote the class, yet you do not `catch` it, or handle that exception.

Since you decided to throw an exception, the program will automatically stop responding (if debugging, it will allow you to see a stacktrace). In order to "handle" this exception, use a `try catch` code block.

```
try
{
    Credit(0.0M); // this will throw an `Exception`, due to the value we passed
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey! The value in credit cannot be 0.");
}
```

I am more concerned that you decide to throw an `Exception`, rather than notify the user. While currently your code doesn't seem to take user input, it isn't a good idea to throw an `Exception` for something like this. The better option would be to generate a text message stating that the value is too low to calculate with, and therefore, ask to retype a new value.

Answer (score -1):

when you call Credit(decimal amount). amount must be great than 0. in our case, looks CalculateInterest is 0.

Comment: i dont see what you mean

Comment: The OP clearly realizes that the `amount` passed into the parameter is 0, which is why the exception was thrown. Please answer, or provide feedback, rather than restate what is already known.